# Neural style transfer using python iterable error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I am trying to implement the Neural style transfer example in pycharm. Link https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/generative/style_transfer#setup. I installed all of the needed cuda software and the cudnn software needed to allow the use of the gpu. However I can't seem to figure out why I am still getting an error TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn. When loading the image.

I have searched for fixes or explanations to why this problem occurs but can't seem to find a good answer. [Tensor` objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use `tf.map_fn`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592980/tensor-objects-are-not-iterable-when-eager-execution-is-not-enabled-to-iterate)
https://intellipaat.com/community/6771/tensor-objects-are-not-iterable-when-eager-execution-is-not-enabled-to-iterate-over-this-tensor-use-tf-mapfn

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
import IPython.display as display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import time
import functools


mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12,12)
mpl.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False

content_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('turtle.jpg','https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/Green_Sea_Turtle_grazing_seagrass.jpg')
style_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('kandinsky.jpg','https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/Vassily_Kandinsky%2C_1913_-_Composition_7.jpg')


def load_img(path_to_img):

  max_dim = 512
  img = tf.io.read_file(path_to_img)
  img = tf.image.decode_image(img, channels=3)
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)

  shape = tf.cast(tf.shape(img)[:-1], tf.float32)
  long_dim = max(shape)
  scale = max_dim / long_dim

  new_shape = tf.cast(shape * scale, tf.int32)

  img = tf.image.resize(img, new_shape)
  img = img[tf.newaxis, :]
  return img

def imshow(image, title=None):
  if len(image.shape) > 3:
    image = tf.squeeze(image, axis=0)

  plt.imshow(image)
  if title:
    plt.title(title)

content_image = load_img(content_path)
style_image = load_img(style_path)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
imshow(content_image, 'Content Image')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
imshow(style_image, 'Style Image')
```

The code which are shown is directly used from the tutorial, I am expecting to see two subplots of the images. But I keep getting the following error

line 26, in load_img 
long_dim = max(shape)

TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or what can be done to solve the problem?

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow have you installed? That tutorial is for TensorFlow 2.0 beta.

Comment: Seems like I am using Version 1.14.0 :( . I am now installing tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-beta1... I will post the result, thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to AKX, the problem could be solved it was just an issue with the Version. Please use TensorFlow 2.0 Beta as suggested by the tutorial!